# addEventListener react redux with mapped dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am currently trying to add an event listener to an application I'm making in react. I'm doing this by hooking into the componentDidMount API, which runs *only once* the component is rendered and not more than that. My problem is that I'm using `connect` from `react-redux` to bind my action creators to `store.dispatch`. I'm not sure how to bind the event listener to the version of the action creator that is bound to the store with dispatch. Is there a graceful way to do this?

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import GridApp from '../components/GridApp';
import * as GridActions from '../actions/gridActions';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { gridAppState, actions } = this.props;
    return (
        <GridApp gridAppState={gridAppState} actions={actions} />
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted")
    // the following line won't be bound to the store here...
    document.addEventListener("keydown", GridActions.naiveKeypress );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    gridAppState: state.gridAppState
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(GridActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get it from `this.props`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mounted")
    // the following line won't be bound to the store here...

    const { actions } = this.props;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", actions.naiveKeypress );
  }
```

I believe you also need to unsubscribe from the `keydown` event on component unmount event though. (even if it does not do that ever, just for sake of completeness and robustness).

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there anywhere in the react-redux docs that shows that the dispatch wrapped actions will be attached to the component props after connecting? Not sure where in docs I might have missed this / could learn this...

Comment: "that shows that the dispatch wrapped actions will be attached to the component props after connecting" `mapStateToProps` result is merged with `mapDispatchToProps` results. Not sure about docs, just check the `connect` function implementation.