# React-Redux: What is the canonical way to bind a keypress action to kick off a reducer sequence?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is a newbie question for react-redux I spent a couple hours hunting around before finding so I am posting the question and then answering for posterity and also maybe code review.

I am using react-redux to create a game where I want to use the WASD keys to move a character around a small map. (This is just a practice example for a larger endeavor). The map simply consists of a bunch of colored `<div>`s.

As I understand it I need to somehow **bind the keypress event to something in the React DOM** in order to trigger mapDispatchToProps and then kick off the reevaluation of the reducers. The problem is, this being a keypress, there is nothing to bind to. I am using jquery to bind the keypress and call the function.

Related queries:

- [React - detect 'enter' key press in change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520587/react-detect-enter-key-press-in-change-event) this one isn't helpful because it just binds to the onChange event of a text area
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events doesn't tell you how to bind and in fact I really couldnt figure out how to use onKeyDown at all with a  element! weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution was adapted from here:

[addEventListener react redux with mapped dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189771/addeventlistener-react-redux-with-mapped-dispatch)

the key is to drop the jquery and to bind it WITHIN the react component using document.addEventListener. here is the excerpt of the working code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// containers
////////////////////////////////////////////
class GameMap extends React.Component{
  renderMap(){
    console.log('renderMap')
    console.log(this.props)
    return this.props.gamemap.map((tile) => {
      //const x = "tile " + tile
      return <div className={"tile " + tile}></div>
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log('GameMap.render()')
    return (
      <div className="GameMap">
        {this.renderMap()}
      </div>)
  } 
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount")
    console.log(this)
    // the following line won't be bound to the store here...
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.props.keyPress );
  }
}
function GMmapStateToProps(state){
  //from here goes into this.props
  console.log('BLmapStateToProps')
  console.log(state)
  const gamemap = state.gamemap.gamemap.map((a) => {
    switch (a){
      case 1:
        return "tile-free"
      case 9:
        return "tile-user"
             }
    return "tile-wall"
  })
  return{
    gamemap: gamemap
  }
}
function GMmapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  //when selectbook called, pass result to all reducers
  console.log('GMmapDispatchToProps')
  return bindActionCreators({keyPress: keyPress}, dispatch)
}
const VGameMap = connect(GMmapStateToProps, GMmapDispatchToProps)(GameMap)

////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// actions
////////////////////////////////////////////
// actions/index.js action creator
function keyPress(key) {
  console.log('keyPress: ', key)
  console.log(key.key)
  var vector = ""
  switch(key){
    case 'w', 'ArrowUp':
      vector = {x:0,y:1}
    case 's', 'ArrowDown':
      vector = {x:0,y:-1}
    case 'a', 'ArrowLeft':
      vector = {x:-1,y:0}
    case 'd', 'ArrowRight':
      vector = {x:1,y:0}
            }
  return {
    type: "KEYPRESS",
    payload: vector
  } // this is an action created
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can basically trigger an action in a `keypress` event handler

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyPress(event) {
    // you may also add a filter here to skip keys, that do not have an effect for your app
    this.props.keyPressAction(event.keyCode);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     document.addEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Your game content</div>;
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {keyPressAction})(App)
```

`handleKeyPress` calls the action creator, that will push action down to reducers.

Answer (score 2):

For those using newer redux in typescript with functional classes, you probably want something like this:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
    return function cleanup() {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
    };
  });

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    console.debug("Key event", event);
    dispatch(handleKeyInput(game_state, connection_status, event.key));
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
  };

  const handleKeyUp = (event) => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, {once: true});
  };
}
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.